# docker ps command returns nothing

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

[image]I'm using a docker container for jenkins and successfully came to the 'docker-compose up -d' step which returned 'starting jenkins.. done'

I now tried 'docker ps' which returns empty.

On trying 'docker images', it returned the jenkins image in the list.

Can you please tell me why this is happening and possible solutions? I'm doing the entire process as the root user.

The docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Comment: Please include your `docker-compose.yml`. The container is likely exiting immediately and it's difficult to figure out what's going on from just a screenshot.

Comment: @tentative, thank you for the suggestion. I've added the docker-compose.yml file now

Comment: Can you delete -d and see error logs

Answer (score 1):

I tried re-creating the issue but the compose file is working for me.

docker ps output:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
96a5965ceab7   jenkins/jenkins   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   7 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins
```

```
$ docker compose up -d
Network "docker-compose-jenkins_net"  Creating
Network "docker-compose-jenkins_net"  Created
Container jenkins  Creating
Container jenkins  Created
Container jenkins  Starting
Container jenkins  Started
```

Could you please check that your root user is able to create the jenkins home directory in the current working directory i.e jenkins-data.

If the root is not able to create the home dir then the container will not start. You can choose another folder in that case.

Regards
Amit Meena

Comment: I used   sudo chown 0:0 jenkins_home -R  for granting ownership to root for the id: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023                                           
Do you reckon this has something to do with the problem?

Comment: I suggest the following 1) check if the container was spawned and then terminted  ``` docker ps -a``` if you can see the terminated container grab the container id and then check its logs using command ``` cat /var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log```

Comment: also, can we try running this (1) from some other directory where the root has full access OR (2) create a folder in /opt say /opt/jenkisn which has full permissions to all and we ran it from there, just to confirm the permission issue